# Winpcap: pcap_breakloop function to pause/stop sniffing won't work

Tags: c++, keyboard, keyboard-events, pcap, libpcap

So for my final year project/dissertation at university I am coding a packet sniffer using C++ and pcap. The program at the moment can sniff packets however I am trying to code it so that when the escape key is pressed, sniffing will stop. This is the piece of code in question:

```
while ((result = pcap_loop(adhandle, 0, packet_handler, NULL)) == 0) {

        if (result == 0)
            continue;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
        {
            result = -2;
        }

        if (result == -2)
        {
            pcap_breakloop(adhandle);
        }
    }
```

When the escape key is pressed nothing happens and sniffing continues until the program is closed. Any help as to why this is not working will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [`pcap_loop`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_loop):

> **pcap_loop()** processes packets from a live capture or ''savefile'' until cnt packets are processed, the end of the ''savefile'' is reached when reading from a ''savefile'', **pcap_breakloop()** is called, or an error occurs. It does **not** return when live read timeouts occur. A value of -1 or 0 for cnt is equivalent to infinity, so that packets are processed until another ending condition occurs.

Because your second argument to `pcap_loop` is 0, it will process packets indefinitely, and won't reach your while loop body unless an error occurs.

Comment: What number would I need to change the second argument to so that pcap_breakloop will work?

Comment: I have tried values of: 1, 2, -1 and -2 and still nothing happens when the escape key is pressed

Comment: You'll also want to your `continue`, otherwise you'll only reach the next instructions in case of failure.

Comment: A value of 1 or 2 now causes the console to close when the escape key is pressed so the breakloop is working, I just need to get the sniffing the stop now and the console to stay open. Thank you for the help!